# Cache eviction in Mondrian

Tags: mondrian

It is not clear from the docs how Mondrian behaves regarding cache eviction.

The ["Out of memory"](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/configuration.php#Cache_management) section on configuration is very vague. Is it correct to say that Mondrian never evicts anything from cache? And if the user performs too diverse queries cache eventually grows to infinity?